# How do you debug the cause of a SQL Server connection error in BHM?

Tags: sql-server, biztalk, biztalk-2010, bhm

How can you debug the cause of a SQL Server connection error in BHM?

Using BHM v4 ...

Connected to the DEV environment and ran BHM analysis fine, and then use the Maintenance mode to fix the issues

Same thing in QA environment. BHM runs the analysis fine, but when I switch to the Maintenance mode ...  select the profile, tick the three check boxes, and click Connect ... I'm getting a network or instance error occurred, error 26 - error locating Server/Instance specified

How is BHM able to connect to run the analysis and then fail to connect to run the maintenance ??

Answer (score 0):

Well the fix that got the maintenance option to connect, was to change the database server details ...

From ... `BTSQAC1\BTSQA1,1433`

To ... `BTSQAC1`

NOTE: this is a clustered SQL Server